# Line following robot problems

Tags: robotics

I am making line following robot using Arduino Uno but every time I connect everything together and upload the code and put the sensors on the line the motor does not work can anyone help me?

I use an L298n motor and Arduino Uno. This is the circuit diagram i am using:

[image: Motor circuit]

And this is the code:

```
// First the line following (IR) sensors
const int irLeft = 2; //Left line sensor is on pin A2
const int irRight = 3; //Right line sensor is on pin A3

//Motor A (Right)
int enableA = 11;
int pinA1 = 10;
int pinA2 = 9;

//Motor B (Left)
int enableB = 7;
int pinB1 = 6;
int pinB2 = 5;
//Define Run variable
boolean run;
void setup() {
pinMode(enableA, OUTPUT);
pinMode(pinA1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(pinA2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(enableB, OUTPUT);
pinMode(pinB1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(pinB2, OUTPUT);
}
void loop(){
  int valleft= analogRead(irLeft);
   int leftsensor = analogRead(A2);  //in the side of motor B
  int rightsensor = analogRead(A3);  //in the side of motor A

   if ((leftsensor >= 700) && (rightsensor >= 700))
     forward();
        else if((leftsensor <= 150) && (rightsensor <= 150))
     backward();
     else if((leftsensor <= 150) && (rightsensor >= 700))
     turnright();
     else if((leftsensor >= 700) && (rightsensor <= 150))
     turnleft();
}
//Motors Foward
void forward(){
  digitalWrite(pinA1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinA2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(pinB1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinB2,LOW);
}
// Motors Backward
void backward(){
  digitalWrite(pinA1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(pinA2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinB1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(pinB2,HIGH);
}
// turn left
void turnleft(){
  digitalWrite(pinA1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinA2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(pinB1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(pinB2,HIGH);
}
// turn right 
void turnright(){
  digitalWrite(pinA1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(pinA2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinB1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinB2,LOW);
}
```

Comment: You give way not enough information. This is how asking "I have a computer for gaming, but it doesn't work. How can I repair it?" Would you be able to do anything about this? I think not

Comment: i will guess .... you have a bad motor, get another one  .... here is another guess .... your program is bad, rewrite it ........... you gave no information, so you will only get guesses, instead of helpful answers

Comment: I edit the question

Comment: Have you tried a very simple sketch to just run your motors in one direction and not doing anything else? If not, try it. If the motors work then, we can exclude a problem with motor wiring or the driver.

Comment: check once individually your IR sensor and driver are working properly

Answer (score 1):

Wire, write and debug just one part of your project at a time.

- Can you just run a motor?
- Can you run it in either direction?
- Can this code do the same for *either* motor?
- Can you run two motors?
- Can you set either of them to run forward, reverse, or to
  stop, independently of each other?

Then the sensors (forget the motors for now):

- Can you read the right sensor and detect light or dark?
- Can you adapt the code to read either sensor?

Then using the above pieces and knowledge:

- Can you make one of the motors run or stop in response to one of the sensors?

Now you have enough pieces - *known working!* - to reassemble them into a device that uses sensors and motors to navigate. If it fails at this point, there's a whole lot you *don't have to debug*, and you can concentrate on whatever you haven't tested yet - your navigation algorithm, any rewiring you've done since you tested each part, and whether you've included the final known-working pieces from your tests, e.g., you used all of the latest and greatest bits of code you developed above.